# Is it possible to customize fonts / color of messages?

Tags: macos, styles, slack

In the Mac client for Slack, I'd like to be able to change the fonts and colors for messages (e.g. have all messages / text in the message area be white text on a black background, or be a larger font, etc.).

Unfortunately, editing the `index.html` CSS under the `Content/Resources` directory in `Slack.app` only changes aspects of the splash screen.

Is it possible to modify these styles, and (if so), how would I accomplish that?

**P.S:** I wanted to create a `slack` tag, because apparently one doesn't already exist. But my rep is apparently too low. Sadness ensued.

Comment: A slack tag now exists. Bob would be proud...

Comment: Over 1,000 people looked at this, and only two people who viewed it also had this question? My apologies to the > 99.8% of you who were looking for a different question.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, Slack for OSX does not support customization of fonts or colors in the message area.  You may make the font larger or smaller via the standard `<Cmd>+` and `<Cmd>-` keystrokes.

You may, however, customize the sidebar portion of Slack, on a per-team basis.

From the [Zendesk help page](https://slack.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205166337-Customizing-your-Slack-theme):

```
Choosing a new theme

1. Open the Slack team you’d like to customize.
2. Go to the Team Menu by clicking the down arrow next to your team’s name.
3. Select Preferences.
4. Click Sidebar Theme.
5. Choose a sidebar theme. To select custom colors, click customize your theme and share it with others.
6. When you’re finished, click Done.
```

This will not change your message window, just the sidebar theme.

Comment: Unfortunately, as of Nov 2016, the "standard `<Cmd>+` and `<Cmd>-` keystrokes" no longer work.

Comment: @Max works for me

Comment: @warvariuc I believe this is a bug when you have multiple teams. FWIW I'm running version 2.3.0.

Comment: @Max I am also using 2.3.0. Try menu `View -> Zoom In/Out`

Comment: I've tried, and 75% of the time, nothing. I tweeted to Slack too, they said it sounds like a bug, probably something obscure that only happens with my setup. Oh well, thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: @Max :I'm sorry you're still having issues.  I just checked my version (2.3.3) and the cmd+ & cmd- keys still behave as desired.  Have you tried removing the app and re-installing?  Also, you might try installing in an OS X VM to see if that makes a difference.  If so, it is most likely something unique to your installation / environment.  I have multiple teams as well...

Answer (score 3):

Slack font can be changed as below

```
/slackfont font name
```

For example, to change to Arial font:

```
/slackfont Arial
```

To reset to default font:

```
/slackfont
```

> This changes the font style(not color) for entire slack including message area
> and sidebar.